# Prevent from "Notice: Array to string conversion in"

Tags: php, security, code-injection

I need help with prevent from "Notice: Array to string conversion in "

```
$stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :emailid");
$stmt->bindParam(':emailid', $emailid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();    
foreach($result as $row)
    {
    echo $row['id'].'<br />';
    echo $row['emailid'].'<br />';
    echo $row['password'];
    }
```

Everythink its OK, `index.php?id=5`

but when i put `index.php?id[]=5`

Return me error

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in
```

What is the best way to check for arrays in this case; `error_reporting(0)` is not a solution I want to find optimized method.

Comment: What exactly you were expecting to happen when putting an array notation inside `get` parameters? `index.php?id[]=5`

Comment: To check for an array: http://php.net/is_array

Comment: Just testing all parameters, in this case you can see the full path disclosure ...

Comment: If you're going to have one option to provide single ids and another to provide an array of ids, call them something different. For example, call the singular `id` and the array `ids`. Then just check which one is set in your php code.

Comment: Just to make sure: you assign $_GET['id'] to $emailid and the line "producing" the notice is `$stmt->bindParam...`?

Comment: `$emailid` is an array. What is the **expected** output?

Comment: If it's always an integer, why are you even asking this question? What are you *actually* trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure in which direction you want this question to go. But let's assume you want - for some reason - make it work either way: `?id=...` and `?id[]=...&id[]=...`

```
if ( !is_array($_GET['id']) ) {
    // just make it an array with one element
    $ids = array( $_GET['id'] );
    // so having a simple type string id is just a special case of the 
    // array case
}
else {
    $ids = $_GET['id'];
}

$stmt = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :emailid");
$stmt->bindParam(':emailid', $emailid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
foreach( $ids as $emailid ) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();    
    foreach($result as $row) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: btw, before someone else is going to point it out: it would also be possible to create a `WHERE id IN (?,?,?...)` prepared statement having exactly the number of parameters as `count($ids)` - but I'd not start there but rely on the query planer to do a good job and the network overhead being neglible. You can still change it if these assumptions are wrong ;-)